# Read files containing Non-ASCII characters in R

Tags: r, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to read a file containing non-ASCII characters in R, please see the screenshot below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zYFc.png)

When I use readLines() to read the file, I get simply few lines of content.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFVzg.png)

Please help! Any answer is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try changing the `encoding` argument of `readLines`?

Comment: yes, but it is the same. in my understanding, there are many control characters. Maybe it is not a problem of encoding.

Comment: I have figured it out by using readBin or read_file_raw from readr package.